# Change image alt with Javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a thumbnail image that when clicked changes a larger image on the page.  I have that part of the code working by just changing the .src with onclick.  Is there also a way to change the alt and title attributes with onclick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **setAttribute** or set the property directly. Either way works, the [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/setAttribute) is the standard DOM way of doing it though.

```
el.onclick = function() {
    var t = document.getElementById('blah');

    // first way
    t.src = 'blah.jpg';
    t.title = 'new title';
    t.alt = 'foo';

    // alternate way
    t.setAttribute('title', 'new title');
    t.setAttribute('alt', 'new alt');
    t.setAttribute('src', 'file.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Both ways are absolutely standard. `src`/`alt`/`title` is specified in DOM Level 1 HTML. I would recommend these properties over `setAttribute` because accessing them is much clearer to read, and there are severe bugs in IE for `getAttribute`/`setAttribute` where the DOM properties different from the HTML attributes.

Comment: I personally use the DOM 0 style of direct property setting myself, and yes there are bugs.

Comment: Thank you for the additional clarification on this question bobince.

Answer (score 4):

In exactly the same way..

```
document.getElementById('main_image_id').title = 'new title'
document.getElementById('main_image_id').alt = 'new alt'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
img.onclick = function() {
  // old fashioned
  img.src = "sth.jpg";
  img.alt = "something";
  img.title = "some title";
  // or the W3C way
  img.setAttribute("src", "sth.jpg");
  img.setAttribute("alt", "something");
  img.setAttribute("title", "some title"); 
}​;
```

Note: No matter which one you're using as long as you're dealing with standard attributes.

Comment: In terms of browser compatibility is the "old fashioned" and "W3C" way the same?

Comment: In this limited case yes, but in general no, IE has many problems with `getAttribute`/`setAttribute` and so you should **avoid** those methods if at all possible. nb. Attributes and properties are different things in many cases! In this case, `.src` when setting behaves the same as setting the attribute `src`, but on reading it will return the full URL the  attribute was pointing to, which will be different for relative URLs. (This won't happen in IE, due to the aforementioned bugginess.)

Comment: @computersaurus bobince, is correct. There are a couple of bugs with IE implementation. The ones I know is `src/href` url relativeness, `for`, `style` and `class`.

Comment: ...plus every property made of multiple words (capitalisation/hyphens), and everything that's a datatype other than `String`: all numeric and boolean properties, event handlers, and also doing `setAttribute` on form fields' `value`/`checked`/`selected` attributes doesn't do what you might think. It's a morass. Avoid.

Comment: yeah I myself have never used them other than for strings, mainly custom attributes.

Comment: Listen to bobince and his wise words.

Comment: @computersaurus as Tim said :)